# Renegotiation in Kurento Media Server

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I'm using Kurento Media Server 6.0 as MCU to do one-to-many communication. I'm trying to renegotiate the SDP for mediaStreams switching. For this I'm using following code :

Let webRtcEndPoint is the created endPointUser on certain MediaPipeline

```
    webRtcEndPoint.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, _sdpAnswer) {

        if (error) {
            console.log("SdpOffer not accepted by kurento");
            return console.log(error);
        }

        console.log(_sdpAnswer);
    });
```

It is returning error

> { [Error: Endpoint already negotiated]
>     code: 40208,
>     data: { type: 'SDP_END_POINT_ALREADY_NEGOTIATED' } }

How could I renegotiate a user with Kurento Media Server without creating whole webrtcEndPoint( i.e. without creating whole new connection between user and Kurento Media Server)?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but Kurento Media Server does not allow renegotiations yet. It's something that is in the roadmap from a long time ago but we did not find the time to implement it.

The only option now is to regenerate the WebRtcEndpoint.

Comment: Something on similar grounds, while screen sharing, lets say there are 2 peers in the room, and peer A decides to share the screen. Will we need to delete the endpoint for peer A and make a new endpoint with the shared screen as the media? This is so that other peers get the updated video of peer A i.e the shared screen.